# How do get a set of Ember Data models as a controller that can be injected to others?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my Ember application, I wanted to have a controller wrapping a collection of models, that I could inject into other controllers.

I've set it up like this:

`app/controllers/zones.js`:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('zone');
  }
});
```

`app/controllers/zones/index.js`:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['zones'],

  zones: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.zones.model')
});
```

This seems like it ought to work, but unfortunately, it doesn't. I get this error in my JavaScript console (in the browser):

```
Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed function () {
"use strict";

        return this.store.find('zone');
      }
```

I've tried moving stuff around, or using ArrayController rather than just Controller, but I still get this error.

This makes very little sense to me, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem – I just needed to set my overridden `model` implementation to be a property, like this:

`app/controllers/zones.js` (injected controller):

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('zone');
  }.property() // `.property()` turns the function into an iterable object for use in templates and the like.
});
```

The main controller is still the same.

`app/controllers/zones/index.js` (active route controller):

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['zones'],

  zones: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.zones.model')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing, [model](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) is the function need to resolve the model **for route** **not controller**. That model then automatically injected to controllers **model** **property**.

**Ember way**

In ember way I would suggest move this **model** definition to the route for controller. Something like this.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (param) {
    return this.store.find('zone');
  }
});
```

This is the Ember way of doing thing. Resolve model in route then have controller to filter / decorate it.

I would also suggest using [ArrayController](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/) instead of Controller since you are handling number of models.

**The other way**

Again if you want to have model resolved in controller. I warn you **its not the Ember way** but you can do it something like this -

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

      //dont override the model property
      mydata: function () {
        return this.store.find('zone');
      }.property('model'),

    });
```

Comment: Yeah, for the main controllers, injection from the route is usually the way to go, but controllers injected by `needs` do not have any route associated with them invoked (since you're not visiting their URL). What I'm trying to do is something like http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/#toc_lightweight-services-with-code-needs-code – but I guess I should just not call it “model”.

Comment: Oh, and as for the `.property('model')`, I'm not sure what the purpose of that is? It would cause `mydata` to be regenerated if someone else sets the `model` attribute, but since `mydata` contains the same logic, that doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @miki , the second method is only used if you don't want to use routes. But in future if something cause model to change your code wont break. But I will suggest first method. I am editing my answer to separate two methods for you

Comment: Also if you dont use Computed or property('') its going to be a function which you can't loop. To make it act like a property we need to use the property('') , Then again if want property to be live updated you have to name the conditions like property('model')

Comment: It's not a question of wanting to use routes or not. Routes are not invoked when using dependency injection. And since using DI is actually documented in Ember.js documentation, I don't really think you can say it's not the Ember way.

Comment: You want a controller model to be used among other controllers. You are using right way to use alias(). But think you have to load model at least once somewhere. That one time call should be in your route. Then you can use alias to inject it other controllers the way you are doing already.

Comment: Since this data does not relate to any particular route, I'd have to duplicate the loading logic to all the routes that need it, and that would kinda defeat the purpose of using DI in the first place, but in any case, thanks for the effort.

Comment: controller are long lived once it got its property its not going to change unless you unload them, reflection updated them or app go to another parent route. resolving model in controllers is :( you will know soon